# 3 phase 4 wire supply advantage

Tags: power-supply

What are the main advantage of using 3 phase 4 wire supply over 3 phase 3 wire? 
What is difference between both?
I have seen a energy meter using 3 phase 4 wire power supply and i am not getting why it is required.

Comment: For tonight's match we have [Wye Vs Delta](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071007231524AAozqZK)

Comment: How do you run single phase appliances off each supply?

Comment: Delta is cheaper for wire use... an extra 20 meters of copper cable 1 inch / 25.4mm in diameter is quite expensive if you don't need it for example....

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about standard mains power systems, then it all depends on what voltages you need to have available. In the US, 3-phase power typically has nominal 208 volts AC between any two phases. If you want to be able to have standard 120 volt AC available, you can not get it from the 3 wires of a 3-phase supply directly - you need the neutral. The nominal voltage between any of the 3 phases and neutral will be 120 volts AC.

So I guess it comes down to what you are going to connect to the power. If it is only stuff that needs 2-wires at 208 VAC (in the US stuff like big air conditioners, electric dryers) or 3-wires with 3 phases (huge motors like for an elevator or machine shop), then you do not need the neutral. If you want to plug in normal household stuff (in the US stuff like lights, TV sets) then you need to connect them between one of the phases and a neutral.

Note: I live in an old warehouse and have 4-wire 3-phase power. In the US, split phase 240 VAC is more typical, so most large appliances expect that. I can only give them 208 VAC by connecting them across two of my phases. While stuff generally works, it does not work as well as it would at 240 VAC. My electric stove takes longer to heat up than it would in a normal apartment with 240 VAC, and my air conditioners do not cool as well. I really notice it when I taker my welder someplace that has 240VAC and I need to adjust my settings down because it gets more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer explained: a standard 4-wire 3-phase source is *usually* Wye connected.  However, there is a notable exception that can literally "bite" you.  This is delta-connected 3-phase source with one winding have a grounded center-tap.  This center-tap is the neutral connection.

The problem with this arrangement is that two legs of the 3-phase supply are 120Vac above ground but the 3rd leg is 208Vac above ground.  Wikipedia has a good explanation: [Stinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-leg_delta)

The reason this is a useful technique that you have both 120Vac and 240Vac available instead of 120Vac and 208Vac.  However, it is nowhere near as common as the standard 120/208V configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One point nobody has mentioned.

In a 3 phase system the 3 phases are 120 degrees apart.    Each phase is the return path for the other two phases.    It's more complicated in delta than wye but the same basic result.

If you connect a neutral then the neutral cable becomes the return path for all 3 phases.    And if you sum the current through that branch from all 3 phases at any point in time it is the imbalance between the 3 phases.      If the phases are perfectly balanced the current through the neutral is 0 amps.

Now....say you lose a phase for some reason..     In a 3 wire system the entire system fails.    In a 4 wire system the remaining two phases continue to operate except now there is a larger current in the neutral cable.    Easy fault detection and phase balance.

We used 4 wire 3 phase in the Navy because of that.    Combat could knock out phases theoretically.    Not sure it matters in residential applications.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, josh. A few quibbles: (1) "*It's more complicated in delta ...*". No, the three phases are also 120° apart in delta and each phase *has* to be the return for the other two. (2) "*... the neutral cable becomes the return path for all 3 phases.*" No, it becomes the return path for the imbalance only. Your subsequent sentence states this and is correct. Tidy up and I can delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about code standards and which state you live in. If you know the code just go by it. 3 wires is fine in a state that requires only that, if you live on the coastline (east/west) more than likely they are wanting to steepen requisites. The only difference is 4 wire can handle the ground better but it doesn't really have an impact in safety as much as some people in these coastline states would have you believe.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but your answer seems to be specific to some unspecified nation. Please remember that you are on an international site. Your answer is incorrect. 4-wire connections are required when a neutral is required to handle single-phase or unbalanced 3-phase loads. 3-wire is acceptable when the load is balanced or if a delta-star (delta-wye) transformer is used between the supply and the load.